# COUNTIFS Formula with Multiple Criteria Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

Can anyone perhaps help me? I am trying to do the following:

I am trying to make the report pick up if the prospect is "Not Selling" if the "Not Selling" tab was ticked in either the first attempt, the 2nd attempt or the third attempt.

I used the formula below to make it work when there was only 1 attempt but when I try adding an OR function to the formula it gives me an array size error.

```
=countifs(Database!$R$3:$R,"="&C45+4,Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE)
```

Is there a way of doing something like what I'm trying to do below?

```
=countifs(OR(Database!$R$3:$R,Database!$X$3:$X,Database!$AD$3:$AD),"="&C45+4,Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE)
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlEER.png)
[report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9pUW.png)

Thanks in advance

Justin

Comment: OR() needs each argument to be the complete test to work.

Comment: I did try this but didn't work. Can you show me an example of what you mean in case I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Like this possibly, if I have followed what you want:

```
=OR(Database!$R$3:$R"="&C45+4,Database!$X$3:$X"="&C45+4,Database!$AD$3:$AD"="&C45+4),"="&C45+4
```

But you may need to sort the detail there.

Comment: I got it by doing this. hell of a long way round

=if(OR(countifs(Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE,Database!$R$3:$R,"="&C37+5),countifs(Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE,Database!$X$3:$X,"="&C37+5),countifs(Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE,Database!$AD$3:$AD,"="&C37+5))=TRUE,sum(countifs(Database!$R$3:$R,"="&C37+5,Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE),countifs(Database!$X$3:$X,"="&C37+5,Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE),countifs(Database!$AD$3:$AD,"="&C37+5,Database!$AH$3:$AH,TRUE),0))